# Как реализовать автоматическую плавную прокрутку ScrollViewer (C# WPF) поэтапно до нижней границы?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имеется ScrollViewer, необходимо реализовать плавную прокрутку до нижней границы, как это реализовать?

Просьба помочь.

Comment: что значит плавная прокрутка? Почему просто не использовать ListBox?

Comment: @vitidev Под плавной прокруткой подразумеваю автоматический скролл до низа. Решил использовать scrollviewer, не вижу принципиальной разницы с listbox.

Comment: не понимаю вашей проблемы _scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(_scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);

Comment: @vitidev Не то=) Фокус сразу перемещается вниз,а необходимо, чтобы фокус перемещался поэтапно.

Comment: ну так сделайте цикл от 0 до _scrollViewer.Scrollabl‌​eHeight

Comment: похоже здесь нужна анимация)

Comment: Вот [отличнейшее решение](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20846310/4267982), рекомендую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем-то vitidev [всё сказал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/582174/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-scrollviewer-c-wpf-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%bd%d0%be#comment775013_582174), но всё же добавлю пример, плавно прокручивающий контент от текущего местоположения до конца:

```
private async Task ScrollDown()
{
    for (var i = this.ScrollViewer1.ContentVerticalOffset; i < this.ScrollViewer1.ScrollableHeight; i++)
    {
        this.ScrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(i);
        await Task.Delay(10);
    }
}
```

... где `ScrollViewer1` это имя скрола. Вызов на примере кнопки:

```
private async void ButtonTest_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await ScrollDown();
}
```

Comment: супер,то,что доктор прописал! Спасибо!

Comment: @vitidev спасибо большое!